# Nikon J1, takes pictures but they are all black, doesn't seem to "see" things, lens not the problem

Tags: lens, nikon, optics, color-black

I have a nikon J1, it has always worked well. Today I wanted to take a picture and the screen appeared black, like something was blocking the light completely or I was trying to take a picture of a black backdrop. I put on and off the lens a few times, it recognizes that the lens is on (when i take it off it asks me to please attach a lens in order to take a picture) but it doesn't "see" anything. On one of the times i took it off and put it back on, it "saw" something but took very blurry/ not still pictures, then when i tried again it went back to being black.

It takes the picture, but the picture is all black, no light gets through

I thought it was probably a lens problem but i tried with my bigger 30-110 mm lens and it doesn't work either. What do you think may be the problem?????

Comment: Just for completeness sake, what lens were you using first? 10-30mm?

Comment: Has this been resolved? Ive been experiencing the same using my Nikon J3 Cam. Is there any site where I can safely download the new firmware version?

Answer (score 5):

My guess, without more info is that you have accidently changed your camera's mode to 'manual'.
Press the 'Menu' button, then click 'Exposue Mode' using the control dial. Next choose 'P' for program mode and press the Menu button.
The camera should now take pics normally.
As an aside, the 10-30 lens has free update available to correct a focus problem if you eventually come across that problem.

Answer (score 1):

See this [thread at dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3745323#forum-post-54640974). Several people have posted there that they have the same problem with the J1 using the 10-30mm. [Nikon issued a service advisory](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Service-And-Support/Service-Advisories/i5hz4dok/Technical-Service-Advisory-for-Users-of-the-1-NIKKOR-VR-10-30mm-f%252F3.5-5.6.html) to correct/repair a design flaw with that lens.

Comment: The OP said the problem persists even when he changed to the 30-110 mm lens.

Comment: @MikeSowsun yeah, I read that. However, the symptoms described exactly matched the discussion at dpreview.com. It is possible that once the problem exhibits, it persists across mfr lenses. Likely? I doubt it, but regardless, there seemed to be more knowledge & experience of these symptoms @ dpreview.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the contacts with electrical cleaner with a cotton bud .The camera body and lens may not be communicating  as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Take the lens off and then put it back on - be sure to hear the "click" when the lens snaps into place. That worked for us.